# Show php as plaintext in single directory

Tags: lighttpd

I'm trying to disable php and show it as plain text in a single directory using lighttpd but I cannot get it to work. I have tried this but it doesn't disable php.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/u" { 
    fastcgi.server = ()
}
```

I have also tried the below to no avail

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/u" { 
    mimetype.assign = (".php" => "text/plain")
}
```

I do know that the directory setting works because I can set things like below and it works fine.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/u" { 
    server.dir-listing = "enable"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere else in your config (which you have not shared), you probably have assigned a handler to ".php".  At that location, you can make your exclusion instead of doing the assignment.

    `$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/u" { 
        server.dir-listing = "enable"
    } else {
        fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => (( ... )))
    }`

(recent versions of lighttpd support the 'else' without requiring a condition)

You might also look to see if perhaps you are assigning the handler in a condition that is evaluated by lighttpd *after* the condition you posted, which attempts to disable fastcgi.